# Is SPARQL 1.0 a subset of SPARQL 1.1

Tags: sparql

Is SPARQL 1.0 a subset of SPARQL 1.1? I suspect that it is. I'm asking because the SPARQL 1.1 grammar isn't written an extension of the 1.0 grammmar. There is obviously a lot of overlap between the two definitions with 1.1 adding grammar rules for the new features but there are other parts that are not shared between the two. If 1.0 is a subset of 1.1 is there a particular reason that it isn't written that way? I would like to create a unified grammar that supports SPARQL 1.0 and SPARQL 1.1 parsing.

Comment: well, at least in SPARQL 1.1 we can do anything we can in SPARQL 1.0, right? Which syntax feature of SPARQL 1.0  isn't covered by the SPARQL 1.1 grammar?

Comment: Maybe helpful, probably not: if you still need the SPARQL 1.1 grammar in ANTLR (v3 or v4), [this project](https://code.google.com/archive/p/sparkle-g/downloads) provides the `.g` files

Comment: "Which syntax feature of SPARQL 1.0 isn't covered by the SPARQL 1.1 grammar?" That's what I'm asking. I believe it is and wanted to confirm that intuition is correct and if it is why the production rules wheren't written as an extension from 1.0

Comment: Thanks for the link. I was aware of that repo. I had to pull the antlr4 grammars from jar files to get them. For such a valuable resource it should be rescued from Google code and put somewhere like github.

Comment: Ok, yes I can't prove it, but I'd expect it. Let's wait for AndyS (Andy Seaborne), he was one of the people behind SPARQL 1.1

Comment: Syntax: Yes SPARQL 1.0 is a subset SPARQL 1.1. Evaluation, nearly - see the red boxes in the 1.1 spec. (RDF 1.1 as @cygri notes and a clarification of intent.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that every valid SPARQL 1.0 query is also a valid SPARQL 1.1 query, but couldn't swear to it.

Some queries will have different results due to the differences between RDF 1.0 and RDF 1.1 (unification of simple literals and xsd:string; introduction of rdf:langString).

The grammar of SPARQL 1.1 supports both Query and Update. That, plus the introduction of many new features in 1.1 Query, may have necessitated some refactoring in the grammar.

Comment: That's what I also think. I mean, it's fully backward compatible from what I know. iirc, RDF 1.1 was finalized after SPARQL 1.1 so there was nothing changed w.r.t.  RDF 1.1. Thus, the difference in the evaluation would also hold for SPARQL 1.0 queries.

Comment: The parts of SPARQL 1.1 that depend on RDF 1.1 were called out as “non-normative/experimental until RDF 1.1 becomes a W3C Recommendation” in the SPARQL spec.

Comment: So I think the consensus is there is a general intuition that it is a subset but there is nowhere in the spec that says, "every 1.0 query is a valid 1.1 query" and there is no simple proof that demonstrates that that statement would be true.

Comment: The SPARQL Working Group (the W3C group that defined SPARQL 1.1) has this in [its charter](https://www.w3.org/2009/01/sparql-charter): “Backwards compatibility with the current version of SPARQL is of great importance. All queries, that are valid in the January 2008 version of SPARQL, should remain valid in the new version and should produce identical results.” Now, WGs don’t always deliver on everything that is in their charter, but at least there clearly was an intention.

Comment: Well, looks like Andy Seaborne confirmed in his comment below the question what we assumed here, *Syntax* yes. *Evaluation*, as you also mentioned, almost due to RDF 1.1

Comment: I will add that I believe that while a SPARQL 1.0 query will parse with a SPARQL 1.1 parser it will not parse to the same parse tree.

Answer (score 1):

I believe in at least one case compatibility with SPARQL 1.0 was broken: in the parsing of the [DECIMAL production](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rDECIMAL), SPARQL 1.0 allowed things like `123.` while SPARQL 1.1 requires at least one digit after the dot (`123.0`).